# Load testing deprecated in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing

Came across this blog => https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/cloud-based-load-testing-service-eol/ saying that - When Visual Studio 2019 Preview 1 shipped in early December, Microsoft announced the plans to deprecate the load test functionality in Visual Studio. Visual Studio 2019 will be the last version of Visual Studio with web performance and load test features.". Have below questions about this:-

1. Does this mean the existing load tests written using the perf testing agents will not work any in Visual Studio?
2. Or does that mean engineers will not be able to use load testing features in Visual Studio 2019 onwards?

Comment: Note, if you want large scale web load testing, that service is also disappearing in March 2020. The blog post offers some alternatives...

Comment: See [this Microsoft forum page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f38aaca5-4e31-473b-9a86-2f5c3df3e12a/web-performance-and-load-test-functionality-is-deprecated-visual-studio-2019-is-the-last-version?forum=vstest) and its links for more information.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a big amount of tests I would recommend staying on your current version of Visual Studio as 2019 will not have load testing features.

For new machines / load generators you should be able to install [older versions of Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/)

[image]

For new tests development [Microsoft Recommends JMeter and BlazeMeter as Preferred Load Testing Tools](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/microsoft-recommends-jmeter-and-blazemeter-as-preferred-load-testing-tools/)

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/cloud-based-load-testing-service-eol/

Comment: I removed my comment to keep peace ✌️, what I don't like is that the blog article says "PREFERRED". Microsoft only says it is one of many. It does remark on its extensibility. I will give you that. It never called any of the products a Preferred Product. If they did that there be a mad rush to use it. I think the blog stretched the truth